# Favorite button withXMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript

I have a link that if clicked or queried from the database to be true the icon displays a full heart and information is saved in the database like so:

```
<a id="fav"  href="#"><i <?if($fe == 1){?>class="faved"<?}else{?>class="fav"<?}?>></i></a>

$("#fav i.fav").click(function(){
                fav= new XMLHttpRequest();
                fav.open("GET", "http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>",  true);
                fav.send();
                $("#fav i").removeClass('fav').addClass('faved');
            });

            $("#fav i.faved").click(function(){
                fav= new XMLHttpRequest();
                fav.open("GET", "http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>",  true);
                fav.send();
                $("#fav i").removeClass('faved').addClass('fav');
            });
```

Currently it works great but the problem I am having is that if a user decides to un-favorite a page it either saves another record or tries to delete again depending on its current state. How do I get it to switch depending on the state. For instance if its not favorited, upon clicking it saves to the db and, without refreshing, click again it deletes from the db.

**UPDATE**

I also have actions in the links to tell my php to either delete or save a record. 
ex: `http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>a=1` (save) `http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>a=2` (delete)

**ANSWER**

Based off of @epascarello's answer.

```
$("#fav").on("click", "i.fav", function(){
                var icon = $(this);
                var makeFavorite = icon.hasClass("fav");
                $.post("http://test.php&u=<?=$user_id?>&a=1",{isFav:makeFavorite}, function(){
                    icon.toggleClass("fav").toggleClass("faved");
                });
            });



$("#fav").on("click", "i.faved", function(){ 
            var icon = $(this);
            var delFavorite = icon.hasClass("faved");
            $.post("http://test.php&u=<?=$user_id?>&a=2",{isFav:delFavorite}, function(){
                icon.toggleClass("faved").toggleClass("fav");
            });   
        });
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why aren't you using `jQuery.get()` or one of the other helpers? http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: This is something you have to check serverside and not clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it one call instead of two. It is the same logic, just make checks! [Assumes you are using jQuery]

```
$("#fav").on("click", "i.fav, i.faved", function(){
    var icon = $(this);
    var makeFavorite = icon.hasClass("fav");
    $.post("http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>",{isFav:makeFavorite}, function(){
        icon.toggleClass("fav").toggleClass("faved");
    });  
});
```

Comment: hmm, I have a check called a, that if it equals 1 it saves and 2 it deletes from my db. How would I add that to the link in your version?
http://test.php?u=<?=$user_id?>a=1

Comment: I am after the same result and I'm using jquery mobile, shayward, can you please post the working code for the add to favorite and what should the database structure be? THANK YOU